# Django-reversion and Apache trouble

Tags: apache-2.2, django

I'm trying to use django-reversion (http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/) on one of my projects, but it won't work on the project that's running on Apache.  It works perfectly fine with a project running on the Django development server, but once I try to use it with the project that's running on Apache, I can access the admin page but I can't access individual model admin pages (I get a 500 error).  Anyone have any ideas and/or suggestions?

Comment: Anything in Apache's error log?

Comment: Yeah, a bunch of "TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html" errors, but I don't see the name of the template it's trying to use anywhere.  I'm assuming it's one of the reversion templates, but I tried putting them in all sorts of directories and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: I just realized that error is probably saying that I have no 500 template in place, unfortunately that's even less information than Apache saying it can't find the reversion templates.

Comment: Can you set DEBUG = True in your settings.py? This should get Django to dump you a Traceback when it fails

Comment: Okay, I set DEBUG = True and got:

Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:  'admin' is not a registered namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been emailing back and forth with the project owner of django-reversion and after a bunch of troubleshooting he came to a conclusion - my URLconf was using (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root) which is apparently deprecated, so I changed that to (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) and now it works.

Comment: I had the same glitch and this fix worked for me as well.
Django 1.1.1, django-reversion 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQLite, does the apache user (or www-data or whatever it is on your system) have permissions to read/write your database?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that I'm using MySQL.  And I'm pretty sure the Apache user doesn't have permissions to read/write to the database.  Should I give the Apache user permissions?

Comment: If you're using MySQL then it'll just use the database user configured in your settings.py, so there shouldn't be a change from the dev server to apache